# #define directives not working outside main() function

Tags: c++, directive

I just started learning C++ today.  With previous knowledge in other languages I am doing fine so far, but I am confused about #define directives.

I have this code in my "review" C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TEST     //object-like macro

#ifdef TEST      //if TEST is defined
    std::cout << "This works!" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifndef NOT_TEST //if NOT_TEST is NOT defined
    std::wcout << "This also works!" << std::endl;
#endif

int main()
{
    //program code
}
```

The above code produces errors, first one being `syntax error : mssing ';' before '<<'`.  When I move the #define/#if directives into the main loop, it works properly:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    #define TEST     //object-like macro

    #ifdef TEST      //if TEST is defined
        std::cout << "This works!" << std::endl;
    #endif

    #ifndef NOT_TEST //if NOT_TEST is NOT defined
        std::wcout << "This also works!" << std::endl;
    #endif
}
```

What about the first block of code is incorrect?  based on the tutorial I am using, I thought that was how it was supposed to be formatted?

EDIT:  I've updated my code to be more clear.

Comment: If you think it has anything to do with the `#define`s, why not remove them and see what happens?

Comment: The program runs fine both with this code block included in the main loop, and without it altogether.  But according to the tutorial I am using, I'm under the impression I should be able to place code like this (anything relating to the preproccesor) in the same spot as my `#inlcude`s.  This program is just for review/practice, it doesn't serve any function.  Just trying to learn :)

Comment: I have updated my post to be more clear on why I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with formatting. In fact, C++ files are formatting-agnostic. The problem is that after the pre-processor parses your file, you end up with 2 `cout` statements outside the `main` function. In C++ you cannot have standalone statements outside of a function, except for declarations/definitions.

Comment: OH!  I feel really silly now.  When I said formatting, I guess I meant "placement".  And also, I didn't realize that you couldn't have `cout` statements outside the `main` function.  Thanks for clarifying that!  That was the answer I was looking for :D

Comment: @EricDavidSartor If you're removed the `#define`s like I suggested you would have seen that.

Answer (score 3):

You should understand that compilation of a C++ program is a two-step process. First the preproccessor is executed that transforms the file according to instructions you gave it (those that start with `#`). Then the C++ compiler is executed on the resulting file.

The “code relating to the preprocessor” here is just the `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` (with the condition that follows it immediately) and `#endif` keywords and, indeed, you can put those wherever you like, since preprocessor doesn’t care about C++ syntax, it performs straightforward string operations.

When the preprocessor runs it plugs your C++ code between `#ifdef` and `#endif` into the file, so the effect is the same as if you just had the `cout << …` line (outside the `main` function).

So, since `TEST` is defined and `NOT_TEST` is not, after the preprocessor did its job you are left with a file that has just two lines:

```
    std::cout << "This works!" << std::endl;

    std::wcout << "This also works!" << std::endl;
```

If you try to compile it, you’ll see that the compiler is not happy, because that’s, obviously, not a valid C++ program.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is using of `cout <<` out of main function.
If you wanna have any output line you can use `#error` directive to abort compilation process.